# Kendo UI Grid- - Default Sort Date Asc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo UI, and am looking to default sort my grid by ascending date, but can't figure out how to modify this. My understanding is that it is part of the data-source section:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerAnimalViewModel>()
                .Name(gridId)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid" })
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(c => c.AnimalId).Visible(false);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.RegistrationNumber).ClientTemplate("<a class='active' href=javascript:viewAnimal(\"" + "#: AnimalId #" + "\",\"" + "#=escape(Name) #" + "\")  >#: RegistrationNumber #</a>");
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Type);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Prefix);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.DateOfBirth).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(DateOfBirth == null ? '' : DateOfBirth, '" + Constants.DateFormat + "') #");
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Sex);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.HMC);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Usability).Visible(false);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Status);
                    columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); }).Title(Resources.Actions);
                })
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()

                    .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(p => p.AnimalId);
                        model.Field(p => p.RegistrationNumber);
                        model.Field(p => p.Type);
                        model.Field(p => p.Prefix);
                        model.Field(p => p.Name);
                        model.Field(p => p.Status);
                        model.Field(p => p.Sex);
                        model.Field(p => p.HMC);
                        model.Field(p => p.Usability);
                        model.Field(p => p.Status);
                    })
                    .Read(read => read.Action("ReadTypes", "Customer").Data("filterData"))
                    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteAnimal", "Customer"))
                )
                .Navigatable()
                .Sortable()
                .Filterable()
                .Pageable()

           )
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

add `.Sort(x=>x.Add("DateOfBirth").Ascending())` in `dataSource`

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerAnimalViewModel>()
                    .Name(gridId)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid" })
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(c => c.AnimalId).Visible(false);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.RegistrationNumber).ClientTemplate("<a class='active' href=javascript:viewAnimal(\"" + "#: AnimalId #" + "\",\"" + "#=escape(Name) #" + "\")  >#: RegistrationNumber #</a>");
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Type);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Prefix);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.DateOfBirth).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(DateOfBirth == null ? '' : DateOfBirth, '" + Constants.DateFormat + "') #");
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Sex);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.HMC);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Usability).Visible(false);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Status);
                        columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); }).Title(Resources.Actions);
                    })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Sort(x=>x.Add("DateOfBirth").Ascending())
                        .Model(model =>
                        {
                            model.Id(p => p.AnimalId);
                            model.Field(p => p.RegistrationNumber);
                            model.Field(p => p.Type);
                            model.Field(p => p.Prefix);
                            model.Field(p => p.Name);
                            model.Field(p => p.Status);
                            model.Field(p => p.Sex);
                            model.Field(p => p.HMC);
                            model.Field(p => p.Usability);
                            model.Field(p => p.Status);
                        })
                        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadTypes", "Customer").Data("filterData"))
                        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteAnimal", "Customer"))
                    )
                    .Navigatable()
                    .Sortable()
                    .Filterable()
                    .Pageable()

               )
```

Comment: Yes, it helps Thanks. :)

But, there's a thing. It is actually triggering the Kendo Grid sort with this (You get the Sort Icon with this right after the column name).

So, I guess if you have to sort the list before showing up it in the grid, you have to do that from the API or backend itself.

Comment: thank you. it's beyond me how this is not in the documentation

Answer (score 3):

Single column sort:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<T>()
    .Name("grid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Sort(x=>x.Add("DateOfBirth").Ascending())
    ....)
```

Multi-column sort:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<T>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Sortable(sortable => sortable.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Sort(s =>
                {
                    s.Add(l => l.F_NAME).Descending();
                    s.Add(l => l.L_NAME).Descending();                        
                })
    ....)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your datasource is what needs to be sorted prior to sending it to the grid.

In your "ReadTypes" action you are probably getting a list of CustomerAnimalViewModel.  You can use a linq query to the list with

```
.OrderBy(d => d.DateOfBirth)
```